# Bootstrap process of the TALQ Smart City Protocol

Tags: rest, protocols

I'm trying to implement the bootstrap process between CMS and gateway in TALQ 2.5.1 protocol (https://github.com/TALQ-consortium/TALQ_specification).

I don't understand how this first POST /devices from GATEWAY to CMS request body should look like - how to pass GatewayFunction with gatewayUri and when and where `functionId` is assigned and by which part (gateway?).

I couldn't find any information on the internet. Are there any additional resource or the bootstrap process examples? Maybe someone implemented this and can share some examples?

From specification (https://github.com/TALQ-consortium/TALQ_specification/blob/main/20230602-Approved-TALQ-Specification-Version-2.5.1.pdf):

> A POST request to /devices with a JSON Payload that provides the gatewayUri in its Gateway function. Although no device class has been announced yet, it is implicitly understood that this GatewayFunction is mandatory and thus is expected at the device representing the Gateway; and other functions can be included at this first step. When receiving such a request, the CMS shall create a unique gatewayAddress and send it, together with its cmsAddress, in the JSON payload of its response. Both addresses must be not NIL UUID.

CMS POST /devices enpoint:
[image: CMS POST /devices enpoint]

Answer (score 1):

Did you get help from anyone? I have already implemented the TALQ protocol at gateway side as a freelance developer (java).

The gateway is responsible for initiating the TALQ bootstrap process by sending this first request to the CMS. The request must contain a Device entity in JSON format in its payload (request body) with at least a GatewayFunction specifying the gatewayUri attribute. Both gatewayUri and functionId of this function are set by the gateway.

The Device entity is defined by the TALQ specification, see the OpenAPI files provided by the TALQ consortium at https://github.com/TALQ-consortium/TALQ_specification/tree/main/oas (especially talq-data-model-2-5-1.json).